# Flatten 3D object to create a template for a 2D texture map

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d-modelling, texturing

I would like to create a texture map for a 3D car model I have.  I am not sure where to start.  I thought maybe I could unwrap the 3D object to a 2D image and then use this as an outline to draw my texture.  Is this possible, or is there a simpler solution?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to create a texture map for a 3D car model I have. I am not sure where to start

**What you are asking about is called UV mapping.**

"UV mapping is the 3D modeling process of projecting a 2D image to a 3D model's surface for texture mapping."

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping

**UV mapping is normally done when creating the model in 3d modelling software, although there may be assets in Unity able to do the same**. To my knowledge Unity is not able to directly UV map.

You can however, change the texture of an object inside Unity as well as assign objects various colours and materials.

> maybe I could unwrap the 3D object to a 2D image and then use this as an outline to draw my texture

**To my knowledge you need 3d modelling software to do so, but yes, it is possible.**

You can try to change it through scripting, but I'd recommend looking into 3d modelling software instead as I believe that if it is possible it will be bothersome.

3D modelling software I know of:

- Blender - Free
- Maya - Licensed
- 3DS Max - Licensed

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply.  I see what I have to do now based on your links.  I need to add 'seams' to the object, so that it can be folded.  I think this is a bit above my skill level as the object is quite complex.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. If you feel the answer was good enough, please upvote it. As an upvote means "This answer was useful".